# Why are the circles of my radio button greying out on hover on my tkinter GUI?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I'm writing a GUI currently and I've run into some weird behavior. Everytime I hover over one `radiobutton` the others circles visually fill their circles as though they've been selected, but slightly greyed. I thought this was just a default behavior. However the only explanation I can find is a mention of it possibly being a garbage collection issue.

**Here's the code**

```
 def create_card():

    print('Placeholder')

    tab_width = root.winfo_width()
    tab_height = root.winfo_height()


    print(tab_width, tab_height)
    tab = ttk.Frame(notebook, width=tab_width, height=tab_height)
    tab.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
    
    notebook.add(tab, text="Add Card")
    notebook.select(tab)


    card_Name = Entry(tab, name="cardName")
    card_Name.pack()

    Frame1 = Frame(tab, width=tab_width)
    Frame1.pack()
    Frame2 = Frame(tab, width=tab_width)

    values = {
            "Frame1" : ("Green",
                        "Yellow",
                        "Red"),

            "Frame2" : {"TButton1" : "Vegetarian",
                        "TButton2" : "Vegan",
                        "TButton3" : "Pescotarian",}
            }
    
    strV = StringVar()
    
    for cListE in values["Frame1"]:
        radioButton = Radiobutton(Frame1, text = cListE, value = cListE, variable = strV)
        radioButton.pack()
        state = radioButton["state"]
```

This function gets called on a button press from a different tab and creates a new tab with all the elements here.(So far just an entry and some radio buttons) I've seen people having a similiar issue with a class based system but with no conclusive answers. Can I get some help?

Comment: I can't duplicate your problem, but it's possibly related to the fact that `strV` is a local variable that gets destroyed by the garbage collector when the function returns.

Answer (score -1):

> Everytime I hover over one radio button the others circles visually
> fill their circles as though they've been selected, but slightly
> greyed

The problem can be fixed.

@Groggyboi forgotten to add the prefix `ttk.` You can add a prefix for every widget or to suit.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import time
 
# root window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x300')
root.title('Notebook Demo')

# create a notebook
notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
notebook.pack(pady=10, expand=True)
 
def create_card():
    print('Placeholder')

    tab_width = root.winfo_width()
    tab_height = root.winfo_height()

    print(tab_width, tab_height)
    tab = ttk.Frame(notebook, width=tab_width, height=tab_height)
    tab.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
    
    notebook.add(tab, text="Add Card")
    notebook.select(tab)


    card_Name = ttk.Entry(tab, name="cardName")
    card_Name.pack()

    Frame1 = ttk.Frame(tab, width=tab_width)
    Frame1.pack()
    Frame2 = ttk.Frame(tab, width=tab_width)

    values = {
            "Frame1" : ("Green",
                        "Yellow",
                        "Red"),

            "Frame2" : {"TButton1" : "Vegetarian",
                        "TButton2" : "Vegan",
                        "TButton3" : "Pescotarian",}
            }
    
    strV = tk.StringVar()
    
    for cListE in values["Frame1"]:
        radioButton = ttk.Radiobutton(Frame1, text = cListE, value = cListE, variable = strV)
        radioButton.pack()
        state = radioButton["state"]
      
if __name__== '__main__':
    create_card()
    root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]